# How do you perform a Guzzle POST request with "Basic Auth" for the current user?

Tags: 8

In my class, I have the following request:

```
    $rest_response = $client->post($endpoint, [
      'auth' => ['admin', 'admin'],
      'body' => $serialized_entity,
      'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json',
        'X-CSRF-Token' => $token,
      ],
    ]);
```

It works because I have a user with the username/password as "admin"/"admin", but when that user's password is changed, it won't work anymore, as expected.

In the logs, I am getting an "access denied" error for the endpoint I am trying to POST to - and the user associated with that error says "Anonymous (not verified)". All other log messages printed out in my controller show the current user's username.

I am running Drupal core 8.1.9.

The question is - how do I use basic_auth to get the current logged-in user's credentials to be passed into the request?

Comment: That would require getting the user's password in plaintext, which isn't possible

Answer (score 3):

You were so close  main thing here is the "Authorization" Header ...

```
 $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
 $account = $current_user->getAccount();

 $username = $account->name;
 // pass would be hard to get as stored hashed 
 //... so you would need to get a bit tricky to "catch" the users password when they log in... 
 $pass = 'admin';
 $auth = 'Basic '. base64_encode ($username . ':' . $pass);
 $rest_response = $client->post($endpoint, [
   'body' => $serialized_entity,
   'headers' => [
     'Authorization' => $auth,
     'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json',
     'X-CSRF-Token' => $token,
  ],
]);
```

And just for fun:

```
  var basicAuthCredential = username + ":" + password;
  var bace64 =  btoa(basicAuthCredential);
  var Auth =  'Basic ' + bace64;
  fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': Auth,
      'X-CSRF-Token': token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => response.json())...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a workaround solution that solved my question. First, I had to allow "Anonymous" users the permission to POST to my custom REST resource. This allowed my resource to be accessed by the POST request programmatically-called by my Guzzle client.
In my REST resource, I am checking for the user's permission, which restrict access for users without the permissions defined (in my case, "access content").

```
/**
 * Provides a resource to get bundles by entity.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "distribution_content_ingestion",
 *   label = @Translation("Distribution Content Ingestion"),
 *   serialization_class = "Drupal\my_module\Normalizer\JsonDenormalizer",
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/entity/distribution_ingest/{distribution_id}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/entity/distribution_ingest/{distribution_id}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class DistributionIngestResource extends ResourceBase {
  /**
   * A current user instance.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * Constructs a Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param array $serializer_formats
   *   The available serialization formats.
   * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   *   A logger instance.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
   *   A current user instance.
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    array $serializer_formats,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);

    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('rest'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Responds to POST requests.
   *
   * Returns a list of bundles for specified entity.
   *
   * @param string $distribution_id
   *   The Distribution ID to ingest.
   * @param array $data
   *   The data from the POST.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   *   Throws exception expected.
   */
  public function post($distribution_id, $data) {
    // You must to implement the logic of your REST Resource here.
    // Use current user after pass authentication to validate access.
    if (!$this->currentUser->hasPermission('access content')) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }

    /**
     * Some code here.
     */
  }
}
```